# Using the XMLHttpRequest object in a Meteor package

Tags: meteor, package

I am trying to import a js file into Meteor, named DomLoader.js, that uses the XMLHttpRequest object. If I try to load the file inside a Meteor package like so:

```
Package.on_use(function(api) {
  api.add_files('DomLoader.js', 'client');

  // more add_files and export statements
}
```

There is an error because XMLHttpRequest is undefined in the DomLoader.js file. How am I supposed to obtain this object? One possible way would be to use one from Npm, but I am not sure whether that one behaves exactly the same as the one in the browser.

Comment: You've typod it, its to be `XMLHttpRequest` not `XmlHttpRequest` in your file DomLoader.js. maybe this is why it comes out as a null reference error

Comment: Sorry, I mean XMLHttpRequest. I will change the question.

Comment: It's very strange; XMLHttpRequest is defined in an other file that I put into api.add_files, but for the DomLoader.js file, I have to use window.XMLHttpRequest in order to obtain the defined object.

Answer (score 2):

Meteor uses a different HTTP module, more info [here](https://docs.meteor.com/api/http.html).

`XMLHttpRequest` in your JS file can be replaced with the `HTTP.call(...)` function that Meteor provides.